# Xpages Wait message processing in BeforeRenderResponse

Tags: xpages, javabeans, message

I have a xpages that is not rendered and in the event BeforeRenderResponse generates a pdf that is displayed on the screen as output, through a call to java bean, which builds a table in HTML and converts it to PDF which is returned to the screen through an outputstream. Since processing takes a while, I'd like to show a message to the user to wait until the file is ready to be displayed. You can do this. I have tried to do both as a text message and an animated gif, both in javascript in the event mentioned above and in java bean, without success. Could someone point me a solution.

Comment: Not sure of the solution off-hand, but `beforeRenderResponse` runs only on the server. Until `beforeRenderResponse` completes nothing is rendered for the browser. So in that event, you cannot interact with the user's browser. You need to look at doing something from where the PDF XPage is triggered, typically a button on a separate page. But if you're launching a separate browser tab, there's no web page yet loaded in that tab in which to add a message.

Comment: And if I put the message and the PDF generation call in the event after render response will it work?

Comment: No, `afterRenderResponse` is still running on the server, before sending the HTML generated in the Render Response phase to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading the PDF with a Full Request you could use an Ajax Download.

Here is an example: http://usefulangle.com/post/68/javascript-ajax-download-file